# How to keep the content of a replaced string with sed

Tags: linux, sed, string, replace

I am trying to use `sed` to replace a line of text that will keep the found text intact and add a colon to the end of it.

specifically, in a file there are a bunch of lines in this format

```
CWMPVendorXEventCodeCutOff              20
CWMP<othertitle>              20
```

and I want to make them into this format

```
CWMPVendorXEventCodeCutOff:              20
CWMP<othertitle>:                        20
```

I'm at this right now

```
sed 's_CWMP.*?\\s_CWMP.*?:_g'
```

But it's obviously not working.
How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed 's/\<CWMP[^[:blank:]]*/&:/' file
```

The `&` in the replacement part will be replaced by the string that matches the regular expression part of the substitution. This would match `CWMP` followed by any number of non-blank characters.  The `\<` at the start of the pattern will ensure that the string `CWMP` occurs at the very start of a word (i.e. not as a substring somewhere else).

Use

```
sed 's/^CWMP[^[:blank:]]*/&:/' file
```

if you need to force a match at the start of the line.

---

Under some circumstances, you could also use

```
awk '$1 ~ /^CWMP/ { $1 = $1 ":"; print }' file
```

This would assume that you'd like to match the first whitespace-delimited word on the line against `^CWMP`, and then add a `:` to the end of that word.  This would, however, "eat up" all whitespace between the two fields on these lines, and replace them with a single space:

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /^CWMP/ { $1 = $1 ":"; print }' file
CWMPVendorXEventCodeCutOff: 20
```

Drop the `$1 ~` if you want to match at the very start of each line, that is, if your lines contains no initial indentation.

Comment: "sed 's/CWMP[^[:blank:]]*/&:/' file" Thanks that worked beautifully! What does [^[:blank:]] do in this situation, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @AnuragKumar `[^[:blank:]]` matches a character that is not a space or a tab. With `[^[:blank:]]*` (the `*` added) we match any number of these characters, i.e. the rest of the string up to (but not including) the space or tab afterwards.  Using `[[:blank:]]` (no `^`) would match a tab or a space character.

Comment: @αғsнιη Yeah. There were spaces at the start of the line in the original question...

Comment: @αғsнιη No, _if_ they want to match at the start of the line, they use the second variant. The first matches anywhere the string is found, but I'll make a small modification to it none the less.

Comment: GNU awk without eating the whitespace is essentially the direct translation from sed: `gawk '{sub(/\<CWMP[^[:blank:]]*/, "&:"); print}'` (doesn't work with mawk but that's because mawk doesn't understand the `\<` word boundary).

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's/\(CWMPVendorXEventCodeCutOff\)/\1:/'
```

should work.

Comment: I think `VendorXEventCodeCutOff` part is not always a fixed string per OP sed command is telling that

Comment: yes, That's totally, the case, I didn't really make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with below Awk command and it worked fine

Command

```
awk '{$1=$1":";printf  "%s%30s\n",$1,$2}' filename| sed -r "s/\s+/ /g"
```

output

```
awk '{$1=$1":";printf  "%s%30s\n",$1,$2}' y.txt | sed -r "s/\s+/ /g"

CWMPVendorXEventCodeCutOff: 20
CWMP<othertitle>: 20
```